# Which Google Maps API can be used to convert zip codes to long./lat.?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What Google Maps API can I use to translate zip codes to longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 10):

You want the Geocoding API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/, pass the zip as the address parameter.